# ReactJS - How to change a component's state based on another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to update a component's state when a different component's state changes.

Here is the main component that contains the form:

```
class IpsumForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    character: 'All',
    paragraphs: 1,
    ipsumDisplayed: false
  };

  handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const target = e.target;
    this.setState({ paragraphs: target.value });
  };

  handleSelectChange = (e) => {
    const target = e.target;
    this.setState({ character: target.value });
  };

  handleReset = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      character: 'All',
      paragraphs: 1,
      ipsumDisplayed: false
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      ipsumDisplayed: true
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <p>Select Your Character:</p>
          <select
            value={this.state.character}
            onChange={this.handleSelectChange}
            name="characterPick"
          >
            <option value="All">All</option>
            <option value="Michael">Michael</option>
            <option value="Dwight">Dwight</option>
            <option value="Jim">Jim</option>
            <option value="Andy">Andy</option>
            <option value="Creed">Creed</option>
          </select>
          <div className="length">
            <p>How Many Paragraphs?</p>
            <input
              onChange={this.handleInputChange}
              name="paragraphLength"
              type="text"
            />
          </div>
          <hr />
          <input
            id="submit"
            type="submit"
            value="Bibity Boppity Give Me The Zoppity"
          />
          <button onClick={this.handleReset}>Reset</button>
        </form>
        <br />
        <IpsumText
          person={this.state.character}
          length={this.state.paragraphs}
          displayed={this.state.ipsumDisplayed}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default IpsumForm;
```

And here is the component that I would like to return the ipsum within a textbox:

```
class IpsumText extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: ''
  };

  handleValueChange = (e) => {
    console.log(data.quote1);
    this.setState({
      value: data.quote1
    });
  };

  render() {
    let character = this.props.person;
    let paragraphs = this.props.length;
    let displayed = this.props.displayed;

    return (
      <div className="returned-ipsum">
        <textarea value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleValueChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default IpsumText;
```

The code I have now doesn't work because a state change from the IpsumForm doesn't cause the textarea onChange handler to run in the IpsumText

I'm wondering if there is a way to do this other than using a lifecycle method because it seems like i'm just overthinking it

Comment: You can try to explore `redux`. The idea is that, connect whatever component to a centralize `store`, and use that `state` everywhere

Comment: The code you have now does not work because the logic behind it is totally incorrect. What do you need to implement? Can you describe, please?

Comment: Yes I know the logic is messed up but what I want to happen is when I submit the form from IpsumForm, that will change the state of my IpsumText to show the quote. But I dont know how to trigger a state change from a different component when I submit the form. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think I need to put my 'value' state up into the IpsumForm and then just pass it down it down to IpsumText?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very simple way of looking at it:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
 state = {
  firstState: 1,
 }
 handleStateUpdate = () => {
  this.setState(prev => ({
   firstState: prev.firstState + 1
  }))
 }
 render() {
  console.log(this.state.firstState)
  return (
   <Foo handleStateUpdate={this.handleStateUpdate} />
  )
 }
}

class Foo extends React.Component {
 state = {
  otherState: 1,
 }
 handleLocalStateUpdate = () => {
  this.props.handleStateUpdate()
  this.setState(prev => ({
   otherState: prev.otherState + 1
  }))
 }
 render() {
  return <button onClick={() => this.handleLocalStateUpdate()}>Click here!</button>
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='app'></div>
```

What this is doing is passing down a function from the parent that updates the parent state, down to the child component. Once you define a function that updates the state of the child component, you can call that passed down function to also update the parent state.

Hopefully, the principle of doing this helps with the issue you're facing.

Here's a link to the code in case you wanna mess with it:

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/HuntingHawk/full/vrpppL/)